# When importing my library via gradle, there is no class inside it

Tags: java, android, github, gradle

```
implementation 'com.github.a-anand-91119:Android-M-Permission-Manager:1.0.2'
```

This is a library I'm working on, I've added it to github and made it importable via Jitpack.

When I import in via gradle in another project, non of the classes are being downloaded:

[image: Libraries imported]

Comment: Well, you could add information on **how** you *made it importable via Jitpack*. How did you pack? How did you publish? Also, the screenshot from Android Studio seems to show the packages of your new project, even if you add a correct dependency, it won't show the classes of this dependency. I guess it would appear under *Libraries*.

Comment: i used this guide to add the library to jitpack: https://jitpack.io/docs/ANDROID/